# Laravel : Generate Simple Unique Serial Number

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a very simple query I want to generate a serial number for every customer but with a specific pattern like

```
    AAA-001
    ...
    ...
    AAA-999
    AAB-001
    ...
    ...
    ABA-999
```

Just like that

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do they need to be sequential? Could you use a UUID instead?

Comment: `var uid = (new Date().getTime()).toString(36).toUpperCase();`
I've tried this but it is hard for client to remember and not in sequenc its random.

Answer (score 2):

PHP supports incrementing alphabet string so code such as this:

```
$string = 'AAA';
$string++;
dump($string);
```

Will output `AAB`.

You can write a simple helper function that will get last serial number from users table, and increments that and returns it to new user:

```
$user = new User;
$user->serial_number = $this->getSerialNumber();
$user->save();

...

public function getSerialNumber(): string
{
   $lastUsedSerialNumber = User::query()->orderByDesc('serial_number')->first();
   // explode by - so you have your tho sequences of the number
   $parts = explode('-', $lastUsedSerialNumber);
   // if second part is 999, increment first part, from AAB to AAC, and set 
   // second sequence to 000;
   if ((int) $parts[1] === 999) {
     $parts[0] = $parts[0]++;
     $parts[1] = 000;
   }
   // increment second sequence if lower than 999
   if ((int) $parts[1] < 999) {
      $parts[1] = str_pad(++$parts[1], 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   }
   return $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[1];

}
```

The code is written without trying, just off the top of my head, but you get the idea.

Comment: does not work, it returns -001